# Postfix SMTP AUTH setup??? Confused

Tags: postfix, sasl

I have setup Postfix on my CentOS and configured it properly.

Now, I want to enable user authentication to avoid any spam deliveries.

I don't want a complicated setup, just a plain txt file which will keep the username/password (or MySQL database if it's also easy to setup) and avoiding the delivery of email without AUTH command in Postfix SMTP connection.

I searched on Google, read lots of articles related to Postfix/SASL but couldn't understand, couldn't make Postfix run with SMTP Auth. Is there any body out there who will be happy to explain the process step by step?

Thanks, looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: The setup you describe is very non-standard.  Do you *really* want to disallow delivery of any mail without authentication, or do you just want to disallow relaying of mail without auth?

Comment: my issue resolve kindly [check answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/987960/491178)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/edition5.html#conf_auth) article from flurdy has all the info on how you can do this. It says how to do it with Mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You DON'T want to make authentication for mail delivery or else users from different mail servers than yours will not be able to deliver e-mails to your server mailboxes.

What you really need from what I've understand is to setup SPAM-bulletproof server. Spamassassin, RBL and greylisting cuts off almost everything if set-up properly.

Check out this article which I have posted on my blog - [AntiSPAM postfix setup](http://blog.stranadurakov.com/2009/07/10/antispam-postfix-setup/).
There you will find copy of my mail server setup which cuts off more than 99% of SPAM without using spamassasin which I doesn't really like due to personal constraints.