# Setup Postfix with SMTP-AUTH over SASL2 with SASLDB for users to send emails

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp, saslauthd, smtp-auth

#### Hello,

I spent the last few days trying to setup Postfix with SASLDB to send emails from my application over SMTP on Ubuntu Server 15.04. I searched, read and tested a lot about it but I can't get it to work. The Postfix and the mail servers are new to me so I hope someone can help me.

#### The last thing I tried is the following:

1. Got a clean install of Ubuntu Server 15.04 x64.
2. Run this script to install and configure Postfix, SASL AUTH:
   https://gist.github.com/richarddong/2634350
3. Fix SASLAUTHD to work with chrooted Postfix by this (3. and 4. paragraphs): 
   https://github.com/webmin/webmin/issues/58#issuecomment-22985720

   To fix **connect() : No such file or directory** error by the **testsaslauthd** command.
4. I created an user with `saslpasswd2 -c -u example.com username`.

   Verified it successfully with `sasldblistusers2`, then tested it with:

   - `testsaslauthd -u username@example.com -p password`
   - `testsaslauthd -u username -p password -r example.com`
   - `testsaslauthd -u username@example.com -p password -s smtp`
   - `testsaslauthd -u username -p password -r example.com -s smtp`
   - `testsaslauthd -u username -p password`

   But all of these returned with: **0: NO "authentication failed"**.

   It accepted only the **root** user and password, like `testsaslauthd -u root -p password`.
5. I checked the configuration and found out it's not using the SASLDB, so I followed this:
   https://serverfault.com/a/547851/317421

   After the SASL, Postfix configuration the results were the same as I wrote above.

   I tried the root user with `telnet localhost 25`, connected, then `AUTH PLAIN base64string`, where base64string generated by:

   `perl -MMIME::Base64 -e 'print encode_base64("\000root\000password");'`

   But returned with `535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure`.

#### This is where I'm now.

Of course I restarted Postfix and SASLAUTHD between these steps.

I tried rebooting the system too but nothing changed.

If someone would be so kind and help me to setup this or got a script for this that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone got the same error this maybe save you from hours of searching.

In order to use sasldb you need to change the `MECHANISMS="pam"` line to `MECHANISMS="sasldb"` in the file `/etc/default/saslauthd`, that was what I missed.

Then restart the saslauthd and the postfix, and it works with the configuration above.