# POSTFIX SASL Authentication ERROR

Tags: postfix

I have raised a query with the below mentioned link, and i have below mentioned configuration in main.cf
[POSTFIX SASL Configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/1036153/postfix-sasl-configuration?answertab=votes#tab-top)

main.cf

---

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases  
command_directory = /usr/sbin  
config_directory = /etc/postfix  
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix  
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix  
debug_peer_level = 2  
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5  
html_directory = no  
inet_interfaces = all  
inet_protocols = all  
mail_owner = postfix  
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix  
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man  
mydestination = $myhostname,<"all other destination list">  
mydomain = <"my domain name">  
myhostname =  <"my hotname name">  
mynetworks = <"ALL IPS">  
myorigin = $mydomain   
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix   
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix  
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES  
relay_domains = $mydestination  
relayhost = <"MY RELAY HOST SERVER DETAILS">  
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples  
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix  
setgid_group = postdrop  
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550   
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus  
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd  
cyrus_sasl_config_path = /etc/postfix/sasl  
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes  
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes  
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

master.cf

---

#File has the below mentioned  
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd      pass  -      -      -      -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       n       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       n       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n        -        -       -       -       smtpd

/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

---

pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN
saslauthd_path: private/saslauthd/mux

With the above configuration i get the below error
postfix/smtpd[20980]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
postfix/smtpd[20980]: warning: unknown[]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: generic failure

Comment: What is your Linux distribution?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put: Postfix communicates with SASL (saslauthd) using files. In the configuration of both, you can specify the path to use. In that path, the following files will be created:

```
~# ls -l /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/
total 4
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Feb 12 11:41 mux
-rw------- 1 root root 0 Feb 12 11:41 mux.accept
-rw------- 1 root root 7 Feb 12 11:41 saslauthd.pid
```

Chances are, your postfix process is chrooted. Which is a good thing from security point of view. This means though that postfix will write it's sasl stuff into /whatever-your-postfix-chroot-is/var/run/saslauthd/

I believe you should not specify a file in your path. So NOT:

> saslauthd_path: private/saslauthd/mux

Because that would lead to postfix looking for private/saslauthd/mux/mux file. That's probably now what you intend.

Either leave that line out completely and use the default path, or specify the sasl path explicitly:

```
saslauthd_path: private/saslauthd/
```

So far for the Postfix side of things.

There is also the SASL side of things. In the saslauthd configuration, you have the OPTIONS parameter. Check out the -m parameter which is /var/run/saslauthd/ by default.

Since your postfix is probably chrooted, it does not have access to /var/run/saslauthd/ path. So change your SASL configuration to /whatever-your-postfix-chroot-is/private/saslauthd/
Like this:
OPTIONS="-m /whatever-your-postfix-chroot-is/private/saslauthd/ -r"

And restart your saslauthd

```
systemctl restart saslauthd
```

If you still experience communication issues between Postfix and saslauthd, suggest you post the output of

```
ps -ef | grep sasl
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory. The two most likely explanations is either that saslauthd is not running, or that smtpd and saslauthd disagree on the name.

Comment: The daemon is running :    i checked with the status command. But I didnt get your second point --->   or that smtpd and saslauthd disagree on the name. How can i check this ??

Comment: You can use the the command `sudo lsof -c saslauthd | grep unix` to see all unix domain sockets that saslauthd has open. You can also use `sudo lsof -c smtpd | grep rtd` to see if postfix is chrooted.

Comment: Actuall the command gives more output, but due to the space constraint, i have placed the first two line. ---> sudo lsof -c saslauthd | grep unix


saslauthd 23203 root    3u  unix 0xffff888079bbcc00      0t0 3194590 socket
saslauthd 23203 root    5u  unix 0xffff888079bbc400      0t0 3194591 /run/saslauthd/mux

Comment: sudo lsof -c smtpd | grep rtd --> this gives no output

Comment: Your lsof does not have the same output format as mine. For me, the third line contains the root directory for the process. The FD is "rtd" and the TYPE is "DIR" and NAME is "/var/spool/postfix". Try sudo lsof -c smtpd | more, and you can probably figure it out. You already have the pathname that sslauthd is using, which in not same as you have configured smtpd to use.

Comment: This command also doesnt given an output. sudo lsof -c smtpd | more

Comment: Try changing saslauthd_path: private/saslauthd/mux to /run/saslauthd/mux. If that does not work, your postfix is running chroot. Mine is, and then you need to change it back, and figure out how to pass -m /var/spool/postfix/private/sslauthd to ssslauthd. Your postfix might yous another root directory.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. This Change doesnt work either : private/saslauthd/mux to /run/saslauthd/mux. I am not sure what you meant in the second statement. I am new to this email server configuration, Could you please kindly let me know with more information ? Still the same error : warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
 warning: unknown[99.999.99.999]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: generic failure

Comment: The answer is that smtpd and saslauthd disagree on the name. The lsof output you posted earlier shows that sslauthd is listening on /run/saslauthd/mux. If your postfix is running chroot to some directory, then it can't access that path. So you have to change the pathname that sslauthd is listening on to something that postfix can access. You need to figure out which directory your postfix is chrooted to, (for me, that is /var/spool/postfix, but it seems that you are not running the same OS as I do), and then figure out how to pass startup options to sslauthd.