# Postfix: how to use SASL authentication?

Tags: postfix, smtp-auth, saslauthd

Hi I am trying to use a very simple sasl authentication. I have been testing the method [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/547282/postfix-how-to-use-simple-file-for-sasl-authentication) but still encounter error.

my server is a fresh install server.
And the command I run:

```
#  saslpasswd2 -c -u `postconf -h mydomain` user1 
Password: 
Again (for verification):
    
# testsaslauthd -u user1@iz.local -p 123123 
0: NO "authentication failed"
    
# testsaslauthd -u user1 -r iz.local -p 123123
0: NO "authentication failed"
    
# sasldblistusers2 
user1@iz.local: userPassword
    
# cat /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf 
pwcheck_method: auxprop 
auxprop_plugin: sasldb 
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
```

My end goal is to authenticate postfix during sending email using sasl. However as you can see I can't even authenticate it standalone

Error log:

```
saslauthd[15846]: : auth failure: [user=user1@iz.local] [service=imap] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
saslauthd[15849]: : auth failure: [user=user1] [service=imap] [realm=iz.local] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

Appreciate if any helps. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add "-s smtp" to the testsaslauthd command and check if it works

Regards